# System call sent warnings to stderr: error: unsupported option (BSD syntax)

Tags: nagios

When we run the Nagios check_procs module in redhat7 os, we are facing below error. By googling we found that we need to reinstall  procps package. We also reinstalled procps package but the module is working for first attempt and then its getting failed.

```
Error: System call sent warnings to stderr: error: unsupported option (BSD syntax)
```

Answer (score 4):

> `Error: System call sent warnings to stderr: error: unsupported option (BSD syntax)`

The problem is that there's a mis-match between the `check_procs` plug-in and your operating system's `ps` command.

Nagios' `check_procs` plug-in spawns the `ps` command to check processes, applying a `scanf()`-style format string to the command's output to find out what it needs to know about running processes.  Given the wide variance in `ps` commands across operating systems, it has to tailor this to each operating system's `ps` command.

This it does when the `check_procs` plug-in  is compiled from source to binary.  There's a 400-odd-line configuration script that laboriously checks each known combination of `ps` arguments+options and scanning format string in turn, until one works.  This combination is then hardwired into the compiled plug-in.

If the combination turns out to be wrong for the actual system where `check_procs` is run, `ps` either generates output in the wrong format (witness [MacPorts bug #28801](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/28801) and [monitoring-plugins issue #1328](https://github.com/monitoring-plugins/monitoring-plugins/issues/1328)) or generates error messages to standard error (witness [Debian Bug #296003](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=296003)) which are picked up by the plug-in and alerted on.  The latter is what is happening here.

This has various consequences:

- If you are building the plug-in from source, you need to build it with the same `ps` command installed as will be installed on the eventual production machine.
- If you are using a pre-built binary, that binary needs to have been built on a system whose `ps` command matches the one on your machine where you are running the plug-in.  If you didn't build the binary yourself, you need to talk to the person who did, or at the very least to the package maintainer if you are using a packaged-up pre-built binary.

Comment: But the check_procs script is working once we reinstall the procps-ng package but it is working only for few minutes. Then same error existing. Please provide a solution for this. i have Redhat 7.1 version installed.

Answer (score 0):

We have done a script for total check process, which solves the **Error: System call sent warnings to stderr: error: unsupported option (BSD syntax)** issue.

Please find the script below.

```
 #!/bin/bash
#
# Script to check Process usage on Linux. Ignores Process used by disk cache.
#
# Requires the bc command
#                $1 $2 $3 $4
# ./check_Process -w 85 -c 95
print_help() {
    echo "Usage:"
    echo "[-w] Warning level as a percentage"
    echo "[-c] Critical level as a percentage"
    exit 0
}

while test -n "$1"; do
    case "$1" in
        --help|-h)
            print_help
            exit 0
            ;;
        -w)
            warn_level=$2
            shift
            ;;
        -c)
            critical_level=$2
            shift
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Unknown Argument: $1"
            print_help
            exit 3
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done

if [ "$warn_level" == "" ]; then
    echo "No Warning Level Specified"
    print_help
    exit 3;
fi

if [ "$critical_level" == "" ]; then
    echo "No Critical Level Specified"
    print_help
    exit 3;
fi

count=`ps -ef | wc -l`

###################

if [ "$count" -lt "$warn_level" ]; then
    echo "Process OK:$count | 'Process' =$count;$warn_level;$critical_level"
    exit 0;
elif [ "$count" -ge "$warn_level" ] && [ "$count" -le "$critical_level" ]; then
    echo "Process WARNING: $count | 'Process'=$count;$warn_level;$critical_level"
    exit 1;
elif [ "$count" -gt "$critical_level" ]; then
    echo "Process CRITICAL: $count | 'Process'=$count;$warn_level;$critical_level"
    exit 2;
fi
```